# Theme toggler not setting id to dark mode

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this React app and I'm trying to set it up where if the main div id is set to `light`, the background is a light color and if set to `dark` it's a dark color. The ThemeContext is so it affects the entire web page.

```
export const ThemeContext = createContext(null);

function App(props) {
  const [theme, setTheme] = useState("light");

  const toggleTheme = () => {
    setTheme((curr) => (curr === "light" ? "dark" : "light"));
  };

  return (
    <div id={theme}> // this needs to change from light to dark when I click on the toggler
      <ThemeContext.Provider value={{ theme, toggleTheme }}>
        <Header theme={theme} toggleTheme={toggleTheme} />
        <ToastContainer />
        <Container className="my-2">
          <Outlet />
        </Container>
        <Footer />
      </ThemeContext.Provider>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I have the main code passed down to the `Header` as props so I can have the toggler inside my header.

```
const Header = (props) => {
  return (
    <header>
      <Navbar bg="dark" variant="dark" expand="lg" collapseOnSelect>
        <Container className="nav_container">
          <LinkContainer to="/">
            <Navbar.Brand>Verdant</Navbar.Brand>
          </LinkContainer>
            <Slider // slider
              onChange={props.toggleTheme}
              checked={props.theme === "dark"}
            />
      </Container>
    </header>
  );
};
```

The slider itself is a simple input

```
const Slider = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <label class={styles.switch}>
        <input type="checkbox" />
        <span class={styles.slider}></span>
      </label>
    </div>
  );
};
```

The slider works fine. When I click on the slider it goes back and forth like it's supposed to.

But when I inspect the page and I click on the slider, the `id` isn't changing from `light` to `dark` like it's supposed to. It stays on `light` no matter how many times I click it.

Comment: First of all, try to change your solution for the dark and lightmode. 
Second, in your Slider Component, you didn't apply onChange and checked property.
Are you sure Slider component works fine?

Put a log in your toggleTheme function to debug, and lastly, share a snippet if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the React app does not "know" when the checkbox is being checked/unchecked. It seems you may have forgotten to wire up the props you have passed to the `<Slider>` component:

```
const Slider = ({ onChange, checked }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <label class={styles.switch}>
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          checked={checked}
          onChange={onChange}
        />
        <span class={styles.slider}></span>
      </label>
    </div>
  );
};
```

We listen for the [`change` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event) on the `<input>` element via the `onChange` prop. This will cause the `onChange()` prop function passed to `<Slider>` to fire, which will in turn cause the `toggleTheme()` function in `App()` to fire. Thus, this will change the `theme` state value in `<App>` and thus change the `id` of the `<div>` element.

```js
const { createContext, useState } = React;

const ThemeContext = createContext(null);

const Container = (props) => <div {...props} />;
const Navbar = (props) => <nav {...props} />;

function App(props) {
  const [theme, setTheme] = useState("light");

  const toggleTheme = () => {
    setTheme((curr) => (curr === "light" ? "dark" : "light"));
  };

  return (
    <div id={theme}>
      <ThemeContext.Provider value={{ theme, toggleTheme }}>
        <Header theme={theme} toggleTheme={toggleTheme} />
      </ThemeContext.Provider>
    </div>
  );
}

const Slider = ({ onChange, checked }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" checked={checked} onChange={onChange} />
        <span></span>
      </label>
    </div>
  );
};

const Header = (props) => {
  return (
    <header>
      <Navbar bg="dark" variant="dark" expand="lg" collapseOnSelect>
        <Container className="nav_container">
          <Slider
            onChange={props.toggleTheme}
            checked={props.theme === "dark"}
          />
        </Container>
      </Navbar>
    </header>
  );
};

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("app")).render(<App />);
```

```css
#light {
  background-color: beige;
}

#dark {
  background-color: darkgray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.production.min.js" integrity="sha512-8Q6Y9XnTbOE+JNvjBQwJ2H8S+UV4uA6hiRykhdtIyDYZ2TprdNmWOUaKdGzOhyr4dCyk287OejbPvwl7lrfqrQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js" integrity="sha512-MOCpqoRoisCTwJ8vQQiciZv0qcpROCidek3GTFS6KTk2+y7munJIlKCVkFCYY+p3ErYFXCjmFjnfTTRSC1OHWQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```